# Fetching Values from models including duplicates

Tags: django, django-views, manytomanyfield

I have my models designed like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_name = models.Charfield(max_length = 15)
    
class Books(models.Model):
    book_name = models.CharField(max_length = 15)
    authors = models.ManytoManyField(Author)
```

The data stored in the authors field is like this:

```
authors Author A
        Author A
        Author B
        Author B
        Author C
```

Now in my views.py file I am trying to query the data like this:

```
allAuthors = Books.objects.all()
for a in allAuthors:
    print(a.authors)
```

The output displayed is :

```
Author A
Author B
Author C
```

Why are the duplicates not displayed? How can I show the duplicates as well? Sorry if I am missing the obvious. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: Is that your actual code? `for a in allAuthors():` should raise an error as a queryset is not callable

Comment: Hi Iain. Its not the actual code. I have simplified my code for this query. I have also removed the brackets after allAuthors(). It does the fetch values now.

Comment: It's working for you now then?

Comment: No. Its only the fetching unique values. Not all the values.

Comment: `print(a.authors)` I would expect to just print the `ManyRelatedManager`? What are you actually getting as output?

Comment: I have shown the output that I am getting in my query. Its shows only unique author names.

Comment: @Shiny show the _actual_ code you have. Or atleast make sure that the code you give _reproduces_ your problem, see how to write a [mre].

Comment: `ManytoManyField`s do not support duplicate entries for the same relationship out-of-the-box, not sure what you mean or are expecting

Answer (score 2):

**try this**

```
all_books = Books.objects.all()
for book in all_books:
    authors = book.authors.all()
    if authors:
        for author in authors:
            print(author.author_name)
```